# Changing Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can someone explain why this doesn't work:

I have a static fragment with a textView and a button in left side on a Activity. In the right side there is a placeHolder (FrameLayout) to switch 2 fragments (both with only a textView) that should be switched when the button (in the static fragment) is clicked. And also has a counter that display how many times the button was clicked and also used to controls which fragment appears, this number should be shown in both fragment on left and the current fragment on right (the visible one). Ok, I can switch the fragments and display the number in the static fragment but in the dynamic fragments this doesn't work...

the code button is:

```
public void sendCount(int count) {

    if((count % 2) == 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right, TAG_RIGHT_1);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.commit();

        right.changeTxtV(count); //this doesn't work
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right2, TAG_RIGHT_2);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();

        right2.changeTxtV(count); //this point causes a NullPointerException
    }
```

I also tried like this:

```
public void sendCount(int count) {

    if((count % 2) == 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right, TAG_RIGHT_1);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.commit();

    } else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right2, TAG_RIGHT_2);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }

    //this block cause a IllegalStateException: No activity
    if(right.isVisible()){
        right.changeTxtV(count);
    } else if (right2.isVisible()){
        right2.changeTxtV(count);
    }
```

And like this:

```
public void sendCount(int count) {

    if((count % 2) == 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right, TAG_RIGHT_1);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.commit();

    } else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, right2, TAG_RIGHT_2);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();

    }

    //this works but show the counter number just before the fragment disappear (before changing fragments) and not in
       // the current one
    if(right != null && right.isVisible()){
        right.changeTxtV(count);
    } else if (right2 != null && right2.isVisible()){
        right2.changeTxtV(count);
    }
}
```

Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly setting text from sendCount function, which I assume is in Activity, you should set that as argument for fragment and inside fragment in onActivityCreated set the count value to text.

inside fragment have a variable count set that variable from `sendCount` method.

```
right.setCount(count);
```

then in `onActivityCreated` inside fragment

```
textView.setText(count+"");
```

The problem with your code is that setText is called before the fragment is displayed. `onActivityCreated` is a method that will get called when the fragment is displayed.

Comment: Yeah!!! It works! 
Actually the method sendCount() is in a interface that a Activity implement, and the methods changeTxtV() were of the dynamic fragments.
I really thought that the method onActivityCreate() was called when the Activity was created and no when its fragments were created...
But as you said it works!!! I recover the counter value (define it static at first), directly in onActivityCreate() and then call the method changeTxtV() and now it works...
Thanks